# Prove $(G \times \mathbb{Z}_2)/K \cong G$ for $K = \{(e, 0), (g, 1)\}$ and $o(g) = 2$ with $g \in Z(G)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I'm a bit stuck on this question, any help will be appreciated, here's the question:

> Let $G$ be a group with an element $g \in G$ such that $o(g) = 2$ and assume $g \in Z(G)$.  Let $K$ be a subset of $G \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ defined by $K = \{(e, 0), (g, 1)\}$. Is it true that $(G \times \mathbb{Z}_2)/K \cong G$?

Here is my attempt:

I was trying to use First Isomorphism Theorem, so I need to find a homomorphism map such that it's kernel is $K$ and it's image is $G$, but I'm having difficulties to find such map.

Since it has $(g,1)$ in it's kernel, which means the map should have something squared in this mapping, but the binary operation from $G$ is not guaranteed to be commutative, so I'm stuck, *i.e.*,

$$(a \ast x )^2 \neq a^2 \ast x ^2$$

If there really does not exist such a map, how do I even prove this statement is false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general result is that if $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of a group $G$ with $HK=G$ and $H\cap K=\{e\}$, then $G\cong H\times K$. (1. $hk=kh$ since $hkh^{1}k^{-1}\in H\cap K$. 2. the map $H\times K\to G$, $(h,k)\mapsto hk$ is surjective with kernel $H\cap K$.)

In the present example, take $H=G\times\{0\}\cong G$. Then, $G\times\mathbb{Z}_2=HK$ and clearly $H\cap K=\{(e,0)\}$. Therefore, $G\times \mathbb{Z}_2\cong G\times K$.

Finally, in general, $(G\times K)/K\cong G$ (the projection $G\times K\to G$, $(g,k)\mapsto g$ is a surjective homomorphism with kernel $K$).

Comment: could you add more details? I'm a bit confuse with the notation

Comment: Please be more specific about what details you would like.

Comment: about $(H \times K)/K \cong H$, how can I apply this with the given example

Comment: Let me know if the above edit is helpful or if you need more explanation.

Comment: I got it, thanks, but could you also explain the two general results you have used, or a hint how to prove them

Comment: Hi, how do you define $(G \times K)/K$ since what I only know is to be a quotient groups $G/H$, $H$ has to be subgroup of $G$

Comment: Identify $K\cong\{e\}\times K$. This should be clear from the statement that $K$ is the kernel of the projection.